# JAVASCRIPT : Mouse wheel turning

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I have a page without scroll.

How i can set alert(for example) when mouse wheel turns?

For example when mouse wheel turns on a element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div').mouseWheel(function(){
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok if you need the mousewheel you should consider the [jquery-mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel). There you can bind on the 'mousewheel' event.

The event also comes with deltaX and deltaY information, from which you can deduce whether the mousewheel scrolls up (deltaY > 0) or scrolls down (deltaY < 0).

See it in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/H9bVp/4/) **with the mousewheel up/down detection**

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="background: green; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    a div
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#mydiv').hover(function() {
   $(this).data('hover',1); // mouse is over the div
}, function(){
   $(this).data('hover',0); // mouse is no longer over the div
});

$(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if($('#mydiv').data('hover') == 1 && $(document).attr('alert-on') != 1) {
        $(document).attr('alert-on', 1) 
        if(deltaY > 0) {
            alert('wheel scrolls up');
        } else {
            alert('wheel scrolls down');
        }
        $(document).attr('alert-on', 0) 
    }
});
```

What it does is it sets a flag on your div when the mouse is over, once a mousewheel event is captured it checks whether you are over the `<div>` with the mouse, when yes it shows an alert box.

It also sets a flag on the document that the alert box is shown, because the mousewheel event is emitted every time you turn your scrolling wheel a little bit which would result in many alert boxes stacked upon each other.

Comment: thanks but my page have not scroll :) I would like to find mousewheel like event or something

Comment: hi, no problem I have updated my answer and the jsfiddle demo, please try.

Comment: thanks dude. How I can find that mousewheel turns up or down?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect scrolling, but you cannot detect whether it was via the mouse wheel, the scrollbar, finger-pad, touchscreen or some other method.

All you get in the browser is a scroll event.

I guess that isn't what you wanted to hear. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know this minuses means :) I just have a questions :D

Comment: actually you can: [official dom3 wheel event reference](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dom3events/raw-file/tip/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-wheelevents) and there's also a [jquery-mousewheel-plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)